# Athena - mismatched input 'where'

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

my query of the form

```
select distinct id from
(select distinct col1 as id from table1) union
.
.
.
(select distinct coln as id from tablen)
where id in ('list of ids')
```

causes the error `mismatched input 'where' expecting {<eof>, 'order', 'limit', 'union', 'except', 'intersect'}`

what is happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to surround the `from` in parentheses

```
select distinct id
from ((select distinct col1 as id from table1) union
      . . .
      (select distinct coln as id from tablen)
     ) t
where id in ('list of ids');
```

Note:  You have too many `distinct`s.  The `union` removes duplicates in the subquery.  So, there is no need for `select distinct` in either the outer query or the subqueries.